# Register user on ejabberd (on localhost) from remote Server with php

Tags: php, ejabberd

When i call this from command on my localhost with ubuntu i can register user succesfully:

```
 ~/ejabberd-18.09/bin/ejabberdctl register thecommanduser localhost abcdefghi
```

But if i call this line of code on my remote host as PHP code to connect to my localhost, where ejabberd is installed, nothing happens

```
exec('sudo /ejabberd-18.09/bin/ejabberdctl register thephpuser xx.xx.xx.xxx abcdefghi 2>&1',$output,$status);
```

I also already added www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Whats wrong with my php code  ?

Comment: How to leave your server wide open to hackers in 3 easy steps.

Comment: you can use **administration api** to create new user. Just go through the documentation.

Comment: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/ thats what Goldwin suggested